# Not able to start the windows service from service controller

Tags: .net, windows-services

I want to start a windows service which I have created from another windows service.
I am using the service Controller which is available. But when I try to start the service I get a message, "Cannot open MyTestService service on computer '.'"

I am working on the windows xp operating system. I have given the Account for the service which I am trying to start as LocalSystem and I also tried with Localservice account.

Do I need to give special permissions to the windows service, to be able to started by another service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you also considered to establish dependencies between your Windows Services. This way when your server reboots Windows will order all services according to their dependencies.

Here are a couple useful links:

- [How to code service dependencies](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jschreuder/archive/2006/12/07/How-to_3A00_-Code-Service-Dependencies.aspx)
- [ServiceController..::.ServicesDependedOn Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.servicesdependedon.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Does it explain the reason? A service won't be marked as running if it immediately returns from the 'Start ()' call (i.e. it's finished). What does your service code look like, basically? Can you start the service through `services.msc`?

Comment: Yes, I am able to start the service from the services.msc. I am trying to start the service in the timer elapsed event as given below

private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serviceController1.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                serviceController1.Start();
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }

Comment: Are you using the right name?  Go to properties on the service and make sure you're using the 'Service name' field ... (I just tested starting one with the ServiceController; and it works fine. If it's not the name, it's permissions).

Comment: Unless your service requires some startup parameters.

Comment: Do I need to give special permissions to the windows service, to be able to started by another service

Comment: I checked the name. I have given the display name of the service. It is automatically popped in the services list to be selected.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about permissions to be honest; my guess is that you'd need at least the permissions of the service itself. But I don't know, so I can't help on that, sorry.

Comment: Try looking in the event log? When a service fails to start there is usually some indication of why in there. (Not sure if this is the same if you are using ServiceController, but still, worth a look) :)